# Is kissing the crotch of an underage girl of age 5-6 illegal?

Tags: criminal-law, sexual-assault, sex-discrimination

I have recently seen a grandma kissing the crotch of a girl of age 5-6 through panties in a public place. She was holding the girl in hands. Is this illegal?  Is it legal only for women to do?

Comment: Which state/country?

Comment: Most jurisdictions shy away from clearly defining what acts are and are not sexual acts according to criminal law and instead leave space for interpreting nuance and context. This question really needs a jurisdiction tag.

Comment: Where did this take place at? Has it happened more than once?

Comment: I mean... did the kid get a boo boo and she was kissing it to make her feel better? Or was it sexual?

Comment: @forest the girl was in normal mood

Comment: @Anixx Was it her crotch, or actual exposed sexual organs? Anyway it's not likely illegal unless it was done with certain intents. Weird cultural practices aren't necessarily against the law.

Comment: @forest she was kissing her pussy via panties. It seems she wanted the girl to handwave to me but the girl had no interest.

Comment: @Anixx Then the description "vulva" is inappropriate (that implies bare skin, and a very specific part of the "panty area"). Anyway that seems completely benign. But again, it depends on intent.

Comment: @forest i do not know who edited the question this way. I want answer on the original question

Comment: @Anixx The original question used the informal term "pussy", which is often considered to be a crass term in English. Whoever edited it assumed you meant the specific part of female anatomy. Also remember that, even if it's legal for both men and women, the law is not entirely unbiased. An old woman kissing a young girl in a way that some might consider sexual is going to end in a very different way than it would for a old mustached man, even if the intent is the same.

Comment: @Anixx What's the mustache got to do with it? Is this [Porn Stache](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/PornStache) or [Beard of Evil](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BeardOfEvil)?

Comment: @PaulJohnson Might be a [molestache](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/molestache).

Answer (score 4):

**[england-and-wales](/questions/tagged/england-and-wales)**

**Is this illegal?**

- **YES, NO, MAYBE**  Context is everything, and it depends on whether this was just playful (for want of a *much* better word) or sexual touching.

Assuming that the "grandma" is actually her grandmother, the likely offence - if there is one at all - would be *sexual activity with a child family member* contrary to [s.25 of the Sexual Offences Act 2003](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/42/section/25?timeline=false):

> 1. A person (A) [*i.e. grandma*] commits an offence if —
>
> (a) [s]he intentionally touches another person (B) [*i.e. the child*],
>
> (b) **the touching is sexual**,
>
> (c) the relation of A to B is within section 27 [*which includes grandparents*],
>
> ...
>
> (e) —
>
> ...
>
> (ii) B is under 13.

**Touching** is defined at [s.79(8)](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/42/section/79?timeline=false):

> (8) Touching includes touching —
>
> (a) with any part of the body,
>
> ...
>
> (c) through anything [*e.g. panties*]
>
> ...

**Sexual** is defined at [s.78](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2003/42/section/78?timeline=false) as:

> penetration, touching or any other activity is sexual if a reasonable person would consider that —
>
> (a) whatever its circumstances or any person’s purpose in relation to it, it is because of its nature sexual, or
>
> (b) because of its nature it may be sexual and **because of its circumstances** or the purpose of any person in relation to it (or both) it is sexual.

A key point to prove is whether s.25(1)(b) is met or not, so again: context is everything.

**Is it legal only for women to do?**

- **NO** - Both males and females (over the age of criminal responsibility of 10) can commit any sexual offence apart from rape which is purely male-specific for anatomical reasons.